# Parsing JSON in Java and data manipulation

Tags: java, json, parsing, data-structures, jackson

I'm super new to Java and am trying to parse JSON and manipulate the data into a final data structure as shown below.

I have this model:

```java
public class StoreInfo {
    private String storeName;
    private String storeCode;
    private List<StoreLocations> locations = new ArrayList<>();
}
```

Here is the JSON response I get from calling Redis:

```
redisResult = "[{
   storeName: 'Walmart',
   storeCode: '0001',
   locations: [ [Object] ]
 },
 {
   displayName: 'Wegmans',
   storeCode: '0002',
   locations: [ [Object] ]
 }]"
```

When I call Redis, I use the keyName `groceryStores` and the fieldName `1`.

I want to have a resulting data structure that looks like this:

```
groceryStores: { 1 : [
  {
    storeName: 'Walmart',
    storeCode: '0001',
    locations: [ [Object] ]
  },
  {
    displayName: 'Wegmans',
    storeCode: '0002',
    locations: [ [Object] ]
  }]
```

I'm having lots of trouble using Jackson to parse the initial JSON string into the type `StoreInfo`. When I try the following, I get an exception from Jackson:

```
StoreInfo[] storeInfoArray = objectMapper.readValue(redisResult, StoreInfo[].class);
```

1. I don't understand how I would create an array of `StoreInfo` objects.
2. Then, to use the key and field in order to create my final data structure.

I'm super new to Java and I have figured out how to do the latter part in Javascript, but how to do it in Java?

```js
// Assuming the JSON response has been parsed

function addResponse (response, key, field, data) {
    response[key] = {}
    response[key][field] = data
  return response
}
```

Answer (score 1):

Easiest Option is create a wrapper class for StoreInfo i.e.

```
class StoreInfoDTO {
   List<StoreInfo> storeInfoList;
   //getter and setters 

}
```

Now use ObjectMapper as:

```
StoreInfo[] storeInfoArray = objectMapper.readValue(redisResult, 
StoreInfoDTO.class).getStoreInfoList();
```

Part2, setting the Value in response :

```
class ResponseDTO {
       @JsonProperty("groceryStores")
       Map<Integer, List<StoreInfo>> props;
      //getter and setters 
 }
```

Now to use it :

```
    ResponseDTO responseDTO = new ResponseDTO();
    GrosseryStores grosseryStores = new GrosseryStores();
    ArrayList<StoreInfo> storeInfos = new ArrayList<StoreInfo>();
    storeInfos.add(new StoreInfo("SN1","1234"));
    ArrayList<StoreInfo> storeInfos1 = new ArrayList<StoreInfo>();
    storeInfos1.add(new StoreInfo("SN2","1236"));
    Map<Integer, List<StoreInfo>> map = new HashMap<>();
    map.put(1,storeInfos);
    map.put(2,storeInfos1);
    responseDTO.setProps(map);
```

Comment: Thank you for the response! The first part makes sense to me. However, for part 2, I need an implementation that allows me to set any key or field, not just `groceryStores` and `1`. I will be calling my cache with many different types of stores, and want to combine the responses into one large hash. I suppose I can do this similarly to how I've done the JS example, by passing the values for key and field into a function and setting them that way

Comment: Hey..based on your comment I have updated the response object.Now you should be able to use dynamic keys. Initially , I assumed you are looking for "1" as key.